# I need fix for error with span on multilanguage website

Tags: html, json

Good day. I am creating my first website that has multiple languages. I use html and json files under the names en for english, and rs for serbian. And now I have a problem because I have between the h1 tag and the span tag and I can't change the span to keep the color it has

"jezik" is name for lang
`<h1 class="heading" jezik="heading">Moje <span jezik="heading-span">Usluge</span></h1>`

I also have a problem with the icons not being displayed, using font awesome html tag.

I tried to do it like this too:
   `"heading": "Moje ", "heading-span": "Usluge",`

but it didn`t work, only work for "heading".

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, unless you are using Javascript to look for custom key-value pairs in a tag and do something, then the use of "jezik" as a key is not valid HTML parameter.

Did some Googling, and if you want the text to change based on the language selected, check out the following article: https://medium.com/@nohanabil/building-a-multilingual-static-website-a-step-by-step-guide-7af238cc8505

As for the font-awesome question:

First, make sure you have included the font-awesome javascript, so the CSS/class tags will work properly.  You need to build a "kit" on the font-awesome website, which will provide you with a URL to use in the page header, with a `<script scr="<url>"></script>`

Then in your page, you can use the  tag to specify the icon you want displayed: `<span class="fa-solid fa-user"></span>`. You have to use "class" populate it with the correct options for the icon you want to display.

Hope that helps!